# Horizontally Positioning Controls inside ListBox

Tags: xaml, listbox, uwp

I am making a UWP app and trying to place two `TextBlock` inside a ListBoxItem. HorizontalAlignment property doesn't seem to work.
I am trying to align the first TextBlock to the left and the second TextBlock to the right. Currently I am trying using Grids. Here's my XAML:

```
<Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
                             SelectionMode="Multiple"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>                                       
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                               Text="{Binding read}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding num}"   
                                                   Grid.Column="1"/>    
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you need to do here:

First, you need to *stretch* the alignment of the `ListBoxItem`, not the `ListBox` itself.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style> 
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Second, you should change `Width="1*"` to `Width="Auto"` otherwise the *num* `TextBlock` might get truncated. Then you can remove `Width="9*"` and add `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to the *read* `TextBlock` so if text will go to the next line if it's too long. You can safely remove `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the HorizontalContentAlignment property to stretch in the ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
```

By default the HorizontalContentAlignment is set to left, and your listItem will not stretch to use all the available space, and that's why it's content will not be alligned properly to the right.

Comment: @ravikumar If you want to use TheMintRubber ways that you should add the code in Justin XL